Should I optimize meta data for each URL in listings even the created by search filters?
On my website there are many products and each of them can be shown with many search filters. I made sure that they had canonical tags but should I change each page's title tag, meta description, H1, ...etc.?

You probably don't want to be indexing all your search filters. You want to focus on a strong category structure and products linked that way.  Too many followable search filters can make a site pretty hard to crawl, as you can soon end up with thousands of URLs.  CMS systems like Magento and Shopify tend to add noindex to filter pages, or block them in the robots file.
With regards to your specific question - if canonical pages are correctly tagged as canonical then no, they don't have to be different.
